# Running NUnit/SpecFlow tests in TFS2017

Tags: selenium, tfs, specflow

I'm not sure whether the issue is with NUnit or SpecFlow but whenever I add the 'Run Functional Tests' task to my build, I get the following error when running a build in TFS2017...

```
2017-05-06T00:11:00.4676774Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test discovery started.
2017-05-06T00:11:00.4676774Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test Run Discovery Aborted . Test run id : 5
2017-05-06T00:11:00.4676774Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: UnExpected error occured during test execution. Try again.
2017-05-06T00:11:00.4676774Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Error : NUnit Adapter 3.7.0.0: Test discovery complete
2017-05-06T00:11:00.4676774Z 
2017-05-06T00:11:00.4676774Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Test run aborted. Test run id: 5
2017-05-06T00:11:00.4676774Z ##[error]System.Exception: The test run was aborted, failing the task.
2017-05-06T00:11:00.5175379Z ##[error]PowerShell script completed with 1 errors.
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Many thanks,

Comment: Could the tests run successful  locally ? And which version of VS and vs test agent are you using?

Comment: Not quite sure what the issue was but switching to MSTest did seem to resolve the issue

Comment: If you are using speckflow you need to make sure that you implement using MS Test. You just need the same adapter for the unit test which provider you use for SpecFlow. More details  please take a look at my reply below.

Answer (score 0):

[Run Functional Tests task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/test/run-functional-tests) are used for below scenarios.

> *Typical scenarios include:*
>
> - Tests that require additional installations on the test machines, such as different browsers for Selenium tests
> - Coded UI tests
> - Tests that require a specific operating system configuration
> - To execute a large number of unit tests more quickly by using multiple test machines

If you are using specflow you need to make sure that you implement using MS Test.

Regardless of the fact which unit test provider you use for **SpecFlow**,  because all the major unit test frameworks provide the necessary adapter for it (this is the same adapter that you need to run the tests from the Visual Studio Test Explorer Window)

So you need to use [Visual Studio Test](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/VsTest/README.md) task in this scenario(Also for handling standard unit tests). For details of the settings please refer this blog: [SpecFlow Tips--Run only specific scenarios in TFS/VSTS build](http://gasparnagy.com/2016/05/specflow-tips-run-only-specific-scenarios-in-tfsvsts-build/)